# Validating client credentials on a server using Java SimpleFramework

Tags: java, https, simple-framework

I am developing a SSL/TLS enabled server using the Java SimpleFramework. I am wondering how to validate client authentications on the server.

On the server side, I am extending `org.simpleframework.http.core.ContainerServer` and overriding the `process()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void process(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    // Ensures client authentication is required
    socket.getEngine().setNeedClientAuth(true);

    super.process(socket);
}
```

This is to make sure that clients authenticate. **Note that if I remove the call to `setNeedClientAuth()`, my program works perfectly.**

On the client side, the following code is used:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, defaultcreds);

GetMethod get = new GetMethod("https://url.to.server");
get.setDoAuthentication(true);

client.executeMethod(get);
```

When enabling authentication requirement, I get the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

I am guessing this relates to the fact that the passed credentials is never validated.

To summarize my question, how should I proceed to validate clients on the server?

Comment: I use SimpleFramework for my own web development. And it does not have a class called HttpClient, so I'm pretty sure you are either confused or are using a super old version of SimpleFramework

Comment: You are right. The HttpClient is part of the apache commons library. However, my question is more related to the server side, on which the SimpleFramework is used. I need to understand how to intercept and validate client credentials after setting `setNeedClientAuth(true)` on the server.

Comment: When I use simpleframework, I don't even use setNeedClientAuth, I just do the auth myself with a token cookie and a /login route.  Also, see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927938/how-can-i-configure-simple-framework-to-require-ssl-client-authentication